# How does a calculator perform division?

Tags: calculator

I wonder how does a calculator perform division , I know he calculate sin,cos and so on with Taylor series , just by adding number . But do you do division?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

Comment: Taylor series also involve division (by $n!$).